# Удаление повторяющегося элемента массива с сохранением порядка массива

Tags: javascript

Как удалить найденный (минимальный по значению) элемент из массива с сохранением его порядка. Ситуация осложнена тем, что мне нужно удалить только первый повторяющийся элемент.

```js
    function removeSmallest(numbers) {
     let someNum = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
     let result = numbers.filter(function(elem) {
        return elem != someNum;
     });
     return result;
    }
    console.log(removeSmallest([2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]));
```

Сложность в том, что через перебирающий метод получается удалить все по условию, а нужно только первый.
Получиться должно [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]

Comment: через findIndex можно найти индекс первого попавшегося

Comment: ок! сейчас попробую! Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через `findIndex` находим индекс наименьшего числа

через `splice` вырезаем элемент с позиции где находится наименьшее число

```js
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
 let smallestNumber = Math.min(...numbers);
 let indexOfSmallestNumber = numbers.findIndex(elem => elem === smallestNumber);
 numbers.splice(indexOfSmallestNumber, 1);
 
 return numbers;
}
console.log(removeSmallest([2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: Годно! Работает. Thank you

Comment: Тогда стоит принять ответ галочкой слева

Comment: @Slon говорят галочку надо тыкать ⬆️ 

Comment: I'm sorry, уважаемый! Я правда забылся насчет этого. Подтвердил галочкой